# How do I download subtitles from a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I want to save all the subtitles available for [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Akqkvx407c8&context=C4da27faADvjVQa1PpcFOFT6G54Wz3WA5JHQwcKyPnuser-BSN_t8=) where there are subtitles available in three languages.

Is there a way to download subtitle files from the video?

Are they .srt files?

I know how to save the video file but I want to use the subtitles with the video offline; any solutions?

Environment: Windows 7 Pro & Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: See also (for the auto-generated transcriptions): http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/downloading-auto-generated-youtube-transcriptions

Comment: @verve, These auto generated subtitles have **a lot** of errors in them....

Comment: I found [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) to be the best alternative. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/927532/500826)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a piece of software that downloads all available subs from a YouTube video with one click in .srt format. It has other features as well: http://google2srt.sourceforge.net/en/ .

Thank you phwd for helping but Google2SRT is super-easy to use and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have Python installed, you can use [getyoutubecc](https://github.com/ihinojal/getyoutubecc), which is a Python script.

Execution is as follows

```
>> python getyoutubecc Akqkvx407c8
```

Then keep the video and .srt in the same folder and you should be able to play in VLC.

For a non-technical way try one of the conversion sites such as http://mo.dbxdb.com/, which will download the .srt within a zip.

[image: Open file in menu]

Select the track from the zip file

[image: Select the track]

And then you should see the subtitles appear

[image: Subtitles at the bottom of VLC screen]

For videos with multiple tracks you will have to dig in and save it from .xml to .srt manually, there isn't a ready made tool out there on the web

```
http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=<LANG>&v=<VIDEOID>
```

Where  can be `en` for English, `it` for Italian and `de` for German.
`<VIDEOID>` is the id of your Youtube video.

For [some videos](http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=fr&v=PILzP-bIeLo&name=french), it appears necessary to specify the name of the subtitle track, as seen on the Youtube page of the video, as a third argument:

```
http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=<LANG>&v=<VIDEOID>&name=<NAME>
```

Comment: I don't know what Python is!  How do I execute?  Sorry, I'm a newbie.  Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @verve it's a programming language. You can use http://mo.dbxdb.com/ to achieve a similar result.

Comment: It seems to work.  Well, when the video plays on YT the Eng. subs plays first by default so maybe that's why it's downloading the Eng. subs.  How do I download the 2 other languages for the same video?  How do I choose to download the other subs?

Comment: You use this `http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=<LANG>&v=<VIDEOID>` and replace with the id to get an .xml file which then needs to be converted to a .srt

Comment: The new URL is http://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?lang={LANG}&v={VIDEOID}

Comment: The github link was updated by the author.

Comment: the github now says "not working!"

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source utility called [4k video downloader](http://www.4kdownload.com/products/product-videodownloader) for this task.

> 4K Video Downloader allows to download video and subtitles from YouTube in the high quality as fast as possible to your computer.

Comment: Note that Chromebleed Checker flags this website as affected by the Heartbleed bug.

Comment: I dunno...smells like spam somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, there's also a Firefox plug-in called [YouTube Caption Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-caption-downloader/).

Answer (score 1):

There's an web-based application that will Download the youtube subtitles and give you the option to save as .txt or .srt format called [youtube subtitles download](http://www.serpsite.com/youtube-subtitles-download-tool/)

Comment: it's a 404 these days.  I did find this one that seems to be not too spammy (as of today LOL) http://www.yousubtitles.com/