# How can I get a transcript of a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downloading YouTube Transcriptions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/downloading-youtube-transcriptions)
>   [How do I download subtitles from a YouTube video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25072/how-do-i-download-subtitles-from-a-youtube-video)

I see options for Closed Captions for some videos.

Is there anyway to get the full transcript of a video?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a little bit?

Comment: Not really. I'm just looking for the textual transcript of any arbitrary YouTube video.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/downloading-youtube-transcriptions

Comment: @Fogest Good catch. I didn't find that question when I searched earlier. Flagging myself as duplicate.

Comment: You don't edit in the duplicate link, it's automatic when closed as such